# DDD один тип сущности на несколько справочников

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, repository, ddd

В DDD для поиска информации из справочных таблиц (lookup tables) могут использоваться хранилища (Repository).

В разрабатываемой программе существует несколько справочников единиц измерения (локализация и ряд других причин). Все единицы измерения из всех справочников намешаны в базе данных в одну таблицу (так, увы сложилось до меня), где ключом является { тип справочника, id единиц измерения }.

Получается ситуация, в которой одному типу данных (единицам измерения) соответствуют несколько справочников.

Как быть в таком случае с доменной моделью? Стоит ли делать индивидуальное хранилище под каждый справочник или указывать Id справочника в идентификаторе единиц измерения? В таком случае не происходит ли "утекание" логики базы данных в доменную модель?

**UPD:** Ниже представлен пример таблиц, используемых в базе данных и программный код. Id справочников имеет составной ключ. *В данном примере он представлен одним столбцом ввиду того, что я не могу раскрывать подробную информацию о программе.*

[image: Пример таблиц базы данных]

В доменной модели был использован следующий подход:

**Единицы измерения:**

```
// Единица измерения
public class Unit {
    public Unit(UnitId id, string name) {
        SetId(id);
        ChangeName(name);
    }

    public UnitId Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }


    private void SetId(UnitId id) {
        if(id == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Не определен идентификатор единицы измерения");
        }
        Id = id;
    }

    private void ChangeName(string name) {
        if(name == null || name == "") {
            throw new ArgumentException("Не определено имя единицы измерения");
        }
        Name = name;
    }
}

// Идентификатор единиц измерения
public class UnitId {
    public UnitId(DirectoryId directoryId, int id) {
        Id = id;
        DirId = directoryId;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public DirectoryId DirId { get; private set; }
}

// Хранилище единиц измерения
public interface IUnitRepository {
    UnitId NextIdentity();

    Unit GetUnitById(UnitId unitId);

    // Нижележащий метод несколько нарушает паттерн Репозиторий
    List<Unit> GetAllUnitsOfDirectory(DirectoryId directoryId);
}
```

**Справочники единиц измерения:**

```
// Справочник единиц измерения
public class Directory {
    public Directory(DirectoryId id, string name) {
        SetId(id);
        ChangeName(name);
    }

    public DirectoryId Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }


    private void SetId(DirectoryId id) {
        if(id == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Не определен идентификатор справочника");
        }
        Id = id;
    }

    private void ChangeName(string name) {
        if(name == null || name == "") {
            throw new ArgumentException("Не определено имя справочника");
        }
        Name = name;
    }
}

// Идентификатор справочника
public class DirectoryId {
    public DirectoryId(int keyPart1, int keyPart2) {
        KeyPart1 = keyPart1;
        KeyPart2 = keyPart2;
    }

    // Первая часть составного ключа
    public int KeyPart1 { get; private set; }

    // Вторая часть составного ключа
    public int KeyPart2 { get; private set;  }
}

// Хранилище справочников
public interface IDirectoryRepository {
    DirectoryId NextIdentity();

    Directory GetDirectoryById(DirectoryId directoryId);

    List<Directory> GetAllDirectories();

    void Save(Directory directory);
}
```

Возникают сомнения при использовании данного подхода. По идее, доменная модель должна абстрагироваться от используемого источника данных. Однако получается, что в данном случае данные определяют модель.

Comment: Одна таблица на все единицы измерения - это нормально. Потому как DDD абсолютно плевать на то, как хранятся данные. Что значит "одному типу данных (единицам измерения) соответствуют несколько справочников" я так расшифровать и не смог.

Comment: Подразумевалось, что в одной таблице базы данных хранятся ссылки сразу для нескольких справочников. Под типом данных я имел ввиду сами единицы измерения, т.е. Units.

Comment: Если это всё разные типы единиц измерения - это вполне нормально.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Если у Вас есть возможность, просветите, пожалуйста по поводу последнего абзаца моего вопроса.

Comment: Смотреть надо по использованию. В целом, в домене вполне можно сделать репозитории для каждого типа единиц измерения, просто Id у них будет сквозной между друг другом. Плюс, вполне можно заиметь общий репозиторий на все единицы измерения, если у них хоть что-то общее есть, для выделения абстракции.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, плохо ли, если id единиц измерения состоит из id справочника и id самих единиц. Дело в том, что такой ключ необходим для использования единиц измерения. Логика в том, что существует тип Параметр, в который включен указанный в текущем сообщении составной id единиц измерения. Только так можно точно определить: какая именно единица измерения описывает параметр. Меня просто смущает, что такая логика базы данных 
определила то, как устроена связь в доменной модели. Хотя логика базы не должна перетекать в доменную модель.

Comment: Ну, выглядит странновато, но ничего критичного с точки зрения DDD не вижу. Особенно, если Id справочника всё таки общий на все единицы измерения этого типа, потому как тогда это получается вполне типовой `Table per class hierarchy` (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass)

Comment: Для всех единиц измерения определен один класс Units, который используется во всех справочниках. Исходя из данного условия, применимо ли Ваше последнее, сообщение к моему вопросу? Дело в том, что id единиц измерения складывается из id справочника (к которому относится экземпляр класса Units) и id самой единицы. Например, в справочнике А с id = 1 находятся сантиметры с id = 14. Тогда UnitId (1, 14).В справочнике B с id 2 находятся santimeters с id = 5. Тогда UnitId (2, 5). Я говорил про это. Просто мне необходимо убедиться, что мы с Вами говорили об одном и том же)

Comment: Может вы пример таблички в вопрос добавите? Чет не соображаю, как это выглядит, всё равно.

Comment: Monk, я внес обновления.

Comment: В целом, с точки зрения DDD не помню никакой проблемы с составными ключами. Особенно, если они скрыты классом отдельным. Т.е. принципиально нет никакой разницы, `Id` сущности представляет собой `int`, `guid` или кастомный класс. Решение в целом вполне рабочее, и это главное.

Comment: Monk, большое спасибо Вам за ответы)
P. S. Я внес некоторые коррективы в в класс UnitId. Теперь UnitId является составным, как и было на рисунке таблиц базы данных.
Остался последний вопрос. По идее, модели предметной области должно быть все равно: где хранится та или иная сущность. Исходя из этого, доменной модели не должно быть ничего известно о справочниках. В данном же случае составной ключ UnitId, пусть и созданный в виде единого класса, говорит о том, что существуют справочники. Получается база данных повлияла на структуру модели. Или в таких ситуациях это вопрос компромисса?

Comment: Думаю, не особо важно в данном случае.